# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'female'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here's the code

```
from numpy import asarray
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
rescaledX = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

and it always resulted in

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'female'
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: It appears as if you set x to 'female' at some point. Where do you get the value of x from? You might also want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], something people can run to reproduce the error. For example, what is `X`?

Answer (score 2):

`MinMaxScaler` works only with numerical features.

it seems that your feature is categorical, therefore you should use `OrdinalEncoder` or `OneHotEncoder` as follows:

```
from numpy import asarray
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

X = np.reshape(['male', 'male', 'female'], (-1, 1))

OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(X)
```

Output:

```
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [0.]])
```